# bundle.min.js not displaying components in html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, react-widgets

[image]I want to display my react components in simple scrtipt tag (a widget)
I created simple react app with npx create-react-app widget_app.
I built a react app in single bundle file i.e bundle.min.js by following these steps:

1. **npx embeddable-create-react-app**
2. added the following in package.json file's script section:

> "web:build": "npm run build && npm run build:bundle",

> "build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"

3. **yarn web:build**
4. It provided me the a bundled file named bundle.min.js at the following path:
   **widget_app/dist/build/static/js/bundle.min.js**

I ran the above bundled file on server by using the following command:

1. npm install -g http-server
2. http-server

My HTML file where I want to display my react widget (bundled file):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Embedded Widget App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this html file not displaying any thing (as in screenshot attached).

Answer (score -1):

This is because source map files are disabled by default, so when to create a build of your project source map file are not generated. To enable add the following line in a .env file at the root of your project.

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = true
```

You can refer this article for more information: [Easy Debugging In React With WebPack Source Maps](https://medium.com/@Linda_Ikechukwu/easy-debugging-in-react-with-webpack-source-maps-5dd80a753cab)